# Using WCF to start a remote process by WMI

Tags: c#, wcf, process, wmi, impersonation

I wanted to start a process (not interactive, small console application) on a remote machine by making a call to WMI from WCF service. This is meant to be a WCF operation that user will run from web application.

I implemented the code from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18146/How-To-Almost-Everything-In-WMI-via-C-Part-Proce), and my operation fails on InvokeMethod function. The error is 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)'.

I tested the WMI connection by using WBEMTEST tool and it works great with the same set of parameters (path to remote server, user name/password, path to application meant to run) both from PC in the same and in the other domain. The account used for impersonation was set up like in [this tutorial](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=280073). Since it works with WBEMTEST, are there any specific things to check when using WCF to make this call? I read that setting wmiProviderEnabled to 'true' in the diagnostics section of web.config might help, but it didn't.

Comment: You might want to check this out too.  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/753179/Running-Programs-on-a-Remote-Machine-with-Web-Serv

Comment: I would prefer to use WMI if it's possible - and tests by WBEMTEST suggest that it should be. I appreciate your suggestion but this approach is not applicable in my case (authentication, security etc.)

Comment: I understand.  I wrote the other article which is why I mentioned it ;O)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix this issue.

First, I applied to my configuration everything what is described in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735120.aspx) under paragraphs 'Enabling WMI' and 'Security'.
It was not enough, and in my investigation I found a possible bug in the aforementioned codeproject source code. In the StartProcess function located in the ProcessMethod class, the connectionScope was not being added to the ManagementClass. Hence, I added a ManagementScope connectionScope parameter to the constructor and then filled the processTask.Scope. Please take a look at my updated StartPtocess function:

```
public static int StartProcess(string machineName, string processPath, ManagementScope connnectionScope, int timeout)
{
    ManagementClass processTask = new ManagementClass(@"\\" + machineName + @"\root\CIMV2",
                                                                    "Win32_Process", null);
    processTask.Scope = connnectionScope;
    ManagementBaseObject methodParams = processTask.GetMethodParameters("Create");
    methodParams["CommandLine"] = processPath;
    InvokeMethodOptions options = new InvokeMethodOptions();
    options.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
    ManagementBaseObject exitCode = processTask.InvokeMethod("Create", methodParams, null);

    return Convert.ToInt32(exitCode["ReturnValue"].ToString());
}
```

ManagementScope is created in ProcessLocal/ProcessRemote constructors.

This fixed my problem. Hope it helps someone.